# Is there a way to only select matched elements but not their children in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, children

I would like to select all elements with the attribute **magic**. But I do not like to get any children that does not have an attribute named **magic**.

Selected elements should not change their order according to the parent with attribute **magic**.

For instance,

**I have an HTML like this:**

```
<div magic="row">
    <div magic="inputWrapper">
        <input magic="input"></input>
        <input magic="input"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <button magic="write">Write</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button magic="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button magic="new">New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I want to obtain is this:**

```
<div magic="row">

    <div magic="inputWrapper">
        <input magic="input"></input>
        <input magic="input"></input>
    </div>

    <button magic="write">Write</button>

    <button magic="delete">Delete</button>

    <button magic="new">New</button>

</div>
```

Is this an easy task with selectors only or should I use loops etc. ?

Comment: You should prefix your `magic` with data and then select the following: `$("*[data-magic]")` in jQuery, that will select all the elements with that attribute. If you want to move the elements, use `$("*[data-magic]).detach().appendTo("wherever you want to append the stuff")`

Comment: Firstly adding your own properties is invalid, you should use `data-*` attributes. Secondly, are you only trying to move the `button` elements to the top level `div`? Is there some other logic you're using to change the DOM?

Comment: If you are selecting them, could you not just get all elements which have the attribute you want (i.e. magic) or do you actually want to change the markup on the page?

Comment: I used the attribute magic only to illustrate the example as it is not the point I am making. That could also be x,y,z or data-* or any other selectable thing.

Comment: I would like to change the markup @Beast-a-tron

Comment: I cannot make it work with detach @somethinghere

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  No, you can think of it as namespacing. For example row.inputWrapper.input or row.write should be the order of markup. Because buttons have the first parent with attribute magic which is a row. There should be a parental order using attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way to do it with selectors. You could loop over every element, if it doesn't have the magic attribute, then just replace it with its child elements:

```
$('*').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if( typeof $this.attr('magic') === 'undefined' ){
        $this.replaceWith( $this.find('*') );
    }
});
```

Since it uses the everything selector (*), it would be good to provide a parent element. Also, using data attributes would be more semantic:

```
$('#parent').find('*').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if( !$this.data('magic') ){
        $this.replaceWith( $this.find('*') );
    }
});
```